# function doesn't display the return value?

Tags: c, function, return-value

Why it doesn't return any value?
The output should be 155 but it always display 0. why?

```
int main()
{
    int i=5;
    printf("%d",fun(fun(fun(fun( fun(i))))));
    return 0;
}

void fun(int i)
{
    if(i%2) return (i+(7*4)-(5/2)+(2*2));
    else return (i+(17/5)-(34/15)+(5/2));
}
```

But if I change

```
void fun(int i) // It doesn't work, case 1
    to
int fun(int i) //It works fine, case 2
```

If fun doesn't return any value in case 1 ( void fun(int i) ), then how come

```
fun(fun(fun(fun( fun(i)))))); this statement is working?
```

Comment: Void doesn't return values

Comment: @CAO....thanks, but that is not my ques. I am asking why fun(fun(fun(fun( fun(i)))))); this statement is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Case 1* is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.8.6.4` *The return statement* says(*emphasis mine*):

> **A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is void**. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is void

but if you do not have a declaration then most likely the compiler is implying the return type as `int` but then there is a mismatch between the declaration and implementation, this as far as I can tell then become *undefined behavior* again. I am able to run this on the latest `gcc` with the same result but I do receive the following warnings:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'fun' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: conflicting types for 'fun' [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no declaration for your `fun` function at the time it is called so the compiler implicitly put a declaration with `int` return value.

In C89 if there is no visible declaration, it is as if the declaration:

```
extern int fun();
```

appeared before the function call. But as your function definition actually has `void` return value, your program invokes undefined behavior.

In C99, the rule for implicit function declaration has been removed and a diagnostic has to be issued.

**EDIT:** Actually as stated by [@Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901858/1119701) you are also having a return statement in a `void` function. This is a constraint violation in C89 (and C99 / C11) and the compiler has the right to stop the translation.

Comment: ok, But why its printing 0? Why its not returning any value as a argument for printf?

Comment: @user2322888 undefined behavior is undefined, tomorrow it could return `42`.

Comment: @user2322888: The only way to answer the question for sure is to look at the generated machine code; most likely, the 0 value is simply an accident of how the undefined behavior was handled.  You will most likely get a different result (maybe even a crash) if you compile with different optimization settings, or add an extra print statement to `fun`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers provided so far (by Shafik and ouah) are correct and complementary (and +1).  But I want to stress something once more: **do not ignore the warnings that a compiler gives you**.  Warnings in C can often save you from a lot of trouble.

When you compile your code (e.g. in `gcc`), you will see:

```
warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
```

This plainly says that you have a function that shouldn't return anything and, still, you're trying to return an integer from it.  As the result type is explicitly declared to be `void`, the compiler chooses simply to ignore whatever you return; this appears as if you always return zero.  This may seem strange but, as what you're doing is undefined behavior, the compiler is entitled to do so.